# Is Async - Await run separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, async-await, task

```
void BtnPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
       {
           var file = await Plugin.FilePicker.CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
           var documentPath = await BaseProvider.CacheDocumentAsync(file.FileName, file.DataArray);
           await documentController.NewDocumentAsync(documentPath);

           var page1 = documentController.Pages[0];
           var environment = new Library.Environment();
           environment.SetVisibleWidth((int)skCanvas.Canvas.Width);
           environment.SetVisibleHeight((int)skCanvas.Canvas.Height);
           environment.SetActualWidth((int)page1.ActualWidth);
           environment.SetActualHeight((int)page1.ActualHeight);
           skCanvas.Environment = environment;
           ShowPage(page1);
       });
    }
```

The above code will run without slowing down the UI. If i remove the Task.Run and put async next to void BtnPage_Clicked, the UI become slow.

Comment: It's right in the documentation: "The work to execute asynchronously" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`Task.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task or `Task<TResult>` handle for that work.

It is `Task.Run()` executing the task on another thread.  `async` does not automatically make code run on another thread, rather it instructs the compiler to transform various structures inside of your method, such as [rewriting `await` statements/expressions](https://www.filipekberg.se/2013/01/16/what-does-async-await-generate/).